# htaccess regex not appending get values

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

First off, apologies for the rather blunt title, I'm a bit of a beginner when it comes to `htaccess`, so bear with me. I'm attempting to create a little hot-link prevention script for the images on my website (you can view the regex with better formatting [here](https://regex101.com/r/VrRVIh/1):

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /

# only allow rewriting to paths that dont exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ruid\.php(?:/t(\d))?/r(\d{2,4})x(\d{2,4})?/([\w-]+)/?$ ruid.php?type=$1&width=$2&height=$3&image=$4 [L,NC,QSA]

# no php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

So for example, if I go to

> www.example.com/ruid.php/t1/r400x500/313ef70

it should point to

> www.example.com/ruid.php?type=1&width=400&height=500&image=313ef70

However, when I `var_dump` the `$_GET` data in `ruid.php`, I receive an empty array:

```
// returns array(0){}
die(var_dump($_GET));
```

After searching around for a little while, trying to find the appropriate flags and syntax for `htaccess` rewriting, I have found nothing to solve my problem.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule with a tweaked regex:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# only allow rewriting to paths that dont exist
RewriteRule ^ruid\.php(?:/t(\d))?/r(\d{2,4})x(\d{2,4})?/([\w-]+)/?$ ruid.php?type=$1&width=$2&height=$3&image=$4 [L,NC,QSA]

# no php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

[Updated Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VrRVIh/2)

- Use a quantifier `+` for the last parameter
- Use `\w` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
- No need to escape `/` in `mod_rewrite` rules

Comment: This does not seem to fix my problem, sorry.

Comment: I have updated the code to what you have said (see post), and still not working :(

Comment: I have updated answer with full .htaccess. Just replace all of your code with this. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` must not be used here.